# Need Help Solving a SQL Question - FIFO Buffer Replacement Strategy

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently working on a SQL assignment that involves a page table and applying the FIFO (First-In-First-Out) buffer replacement strategy.

Here's a brief overview of the task:

I have a page table (Table 1) with columns like PAGE_ID, pin-count, dirty bit, lastaccessed_time, firstloaded_time, and access_count. The goal is to identify the PAGE_ID of the page that needs to be written back to disk using the FIFO strategy.

If anyone could guide me through the SQL query or logic to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here's the table structure for your reference:

```
CREATE TABLE PageTable (
    PAGE_ID INT,
    pin_count INT,
    dirty_bit INT,
    lastaccessed_time INT,
    firstloaded_time INT,
    access_count INT
);
```

```
INSERT INTO PageTable VALUES
(1, 0, 1, 94, 12, 4),
(2, 2, 1, 23, 15, 44),
(3, 0, 0, 101, 46, 13),
(4, 0, 1, 44, 32, 4333),
(5, 0, 0, 23, 19, 222),
(6, 3, 0, 64, 2, 3423423);
```

Comment: Do you have trouble finding a page with the earliest load time? Or is it about the FIFO cache management algorithm in general?